# How do you improve performance on a pig job that has very skewed data?

Tags: apache-pig

I am running a pig script that performs a GROUP BY and a nested FOREACH that takes hours to run due to one or two reduce tasks.  For example:

```
B = GROUP A BY (fld1, fld2) parallel 50;

C = FOREACH B {
   U = A.fld1;
   DIST = DISTINCT U;
   GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT_STAR(DIST);
}
```

Upon examining the counters for the slow tasks, I realized that it looks like the two reducers are processing through a lot more data than the other tasks.  Basically, my understanding is that the data is very skewed and so the tasks that are "slow" are in fact doing more work than the fast tasks.  I'm just wondering how to improve performance?  I hate increasing the parallelism to try to split up the work but is that the only way?

Answer (score 2):

The first option is to use a custom partitioner. [Check out the documentation on `GROUP` for more info (check out `PARTITION BY`, specifically).](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#GROUP) Unfortunately, you probably have to write your own custom partitioner here. In your custom partitioner, send the first huge set of keys to reducer 0, send the next set to reducer 1, then do the standard hash partitioning across what's left. What this does is lets one reducer handle the big ones exclusively, while the others get multiple sets of keys. This doesn't always solve the problem with bad skew, though.

How valuable is the count for those two huge sets of data? I see huge skew a lot when things like `NULL` or empty string. If they aren't that valuable, filter them out before the `GROUP BY`.