# some mappers take more time ( and splits) than others

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, skew

I have a pig script that does log processing of diff applications and calculate few metrics.  While it is running, I observe that some mappers alone take more time/splits to process compared to others. 
For eg, if there are 25 mappers , 21 would finish within 2 or 3 mins and remaining 4 takes 30 mins. I am wondering whats could cause this skewness and how to fix it?

Simpler version of my task is as follows. 
This Pig script go through huge set of log files from different applications. For each log , it parses the data using regex and reports metrics like traffic count,avg resp time for various dimensions per hour

The code is really long and does multiple for-each with filters, one join & one big GROUP BY with multiple dimensions as follows. 
C3 = GROUP C2 by ( appName, timestamp, consumerId, resourceName, methodName, apiName, manifestId, version, siteId, status) ;

Seems the input file format I am processing controls the split size , and each split is in different size. So I dont have much control over splits. I tried not to combine splits using pig.noSplitCombination
as true, but still the result is same.

**Update:**  couldn't proceed with much solutions. This is not data skew issue too. Anyway , removing some null values used in the join helped some. But the issue still remains. Keeping the question open

Comment: Are all mappers in the same stage, or do the 21 mappers prepare the input for the final 4? -- When you group, is your input roughly equally distributed over the groups?

Comment: How to check if all the mappers are in the same stage or some are preparing input for the final 4 ? 
My groupings are not equally distributed .  one group always gets around 90% of the count .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you improve performance on a pig job that has very skewed data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867846/how-do-you-improve-performance-on-a-pig-job-that-has-very-skewed-data)